# How to make button paypal with our variable total in php

Tags: php, paypal

Hy guys, How to make button paypal with our variable $total, I make button paypal automatic in paypal.com, but I don't know how to change code with my variable total in my program, and change this value with my email `<input type="hidden" name="hosted_button_id" value="6GRSJ868MQYPS">`

this is my code can any solution with my problem ?

```
<form action="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post" target="_top">
<input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_s-xclick">
<input type="hidden" name="hosted_button_id" value="6GRSJ868MQYPS">
<input type="image" src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/en_US/i/btn/btn_buynowCC_LG.gif" border="0" name="submit" alt="PayPal - The safer, easier way to pay online!">
<img alt="" border="0" src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/en_US/i/scr/pixel.gif" width="1" height="1">
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Hosted buttons hide those parameters, so you won't be able to dynamically adjust the $total when the page loads.  If you want to do that you'll need to create a button that is not hosted, and then you would have an "amount" parameter you could pass your $total into.